# How can I fix "unable to update registry, network failure seems to have happened" error when building with cargo in Docker container?

Tags: docker, rust, dockerfile, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build a program with `cargo` in a Docker container but it fails:

```
# Compile KissMP
FROM --platform=arm64 ubuntu:20.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cargo
RUN apt-get install -y git

# Clone & Build KissMP
WORKDIR /build
RUN git clone -b lib https://github.com/vulcan-dev/KISS-multiplayer.git
WORKDIR /KISS-multiplayer
WORKDIR /build/KISS-multiplayer/kissmp-server/
RUN cargo build --release
```

```
#24 2.299     Updating crates.io index
#24 681.7 error: failed to get `anyhow` as a dependency of package `kissmp-bridge v0.5.0 (/build/KISS-multiplayer/kissmp-bridge)`
#24 681.7 
#24 681.7 Caused by:
#24 681.7   failed to load source for dependency `anyhow`
#24 681.7 
#24 681.7 Caused by:
#24 681.7   Unable to update registry `crates-io`
#24 681.7 
#24 681.7 Caused by:
#24 681.7   failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
#24 681.7 
#24 681.7 Caused by:
#24 681.7   network failure seems to have happened
#24 681.7   if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
#24 681.7   https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli
#24 681.7 
#24 681.7 Caused by:
#24 681.7   SSL error: unknown error; class=Ssl (16)
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Note: I cannot use Alpine

Comment: Weird. I'd assume it's an intermittent failure, but you've probably tried more than once. Are you using proxies via `https_proxy` or somesuch? You could try adding `ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true`, since `RUN git clone …` seems to be working.

Comment: Forgot to update, I did this and it worked. Thanks anyways, I'll close this now :)

Answer (score 2):

I added `CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true` before `cargo build` and now it works.

Comment: From the doc:   CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI — Enables the use of the git executable to fetch, see net.git-fetch-with-cli.

Answer (score -1):

basically ahash version in cargo.toml was either 0.7..7 or 0.8.7, but the build seems to fail with it

cargo update -p ahash:0.8.7 --precise 0.8.6 to update the cargo tree

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35471366)